# What's inside scope, and attrs variables/objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, object

What is defined within `scope` and `attrs` variable there? How to see what's there?

Also, how would I use `scope` variable to write to fields `ID` and `scopeID`?

Also, why `alert(scope.$id);` keep pointing to 001? Don't I have 2 apps? At least 2 separate entities?

```
    <script>
        var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
        firstApp.directive('myFirstApp', function() {
            var variable = function(scope, element, attrs) {

                alert(scope.$id);
                $.each(elemArray, function(scope) {
                    $(this).on('click', function(scope) {
                        var id = $(this).attr("id");
                        scope.ID = $(this).attr("id");; // how to write to ID field here
                        alert($(this).attr("id"););
                    });
                });
            };
            return {
                restrict: 'AEC',
                link: variable
            };
        });
    </script>

    <my-first-app>
        <button id="a1">button 1</button>
        <button id="a2">button 2</button>
        <br />My ID: {{ ID }}
        <br />My Scope ID: {{ scopeID }}
    </my-first-app>
    <br />
    <my-first-app>
        <button id="b1">button 1</button>
        <button id="b2">button 2</button>
        <br />My ID: {{ ID }}
        <br />My Scope ID: {{ scopeID }}
    </my-first-app>
```

Comment: There is a chrome plugin named AngularJs, with it you can see what's in scope.

Comment: Scope is inherited unless otherwise specified. So both apps are inheriting the same parent scope. If you want each directive to have its own child scope, add "scope:true" to your directive definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MJCXiMycJ6zg1DLQ0Q8T?p=preview)

If you want to see what is on your directive's "scope", you can use angular.extend to shallow copy the scope's properties to another object, and then bind the object to your view:

**Directive**

```
   app.directive('myFirstApp', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      link:function(scope, element, attr) {
         var inScope = {};
         angular.extend(inScope, scope);
         scope.inScope = inScope;
         scope.inAttr = attr;
      }
    }
  })
```

**HTML**

```
<div my-first-app>
  {{inScope }}
  {{inAttr}}
</div>
```

Comment: I believe `restrict: 'A'`, should be `restrict: 'AEC'`, for this to work.